# How can I create a file and make it executable without typing the filename twice?

Tags: bash, arguments, one-liner

I would like to be able to `chmod +x` and `touch` a file in one go without having to list the file name twice as in `touch foo && chmod +x foo`. Is there a way to do this is in one whack? Here is some pseudo-code explanation describing the expected behavior:

```bash
chmod <placeholder> && touch <placeholder> <-redirect- "filename"
```

I get sick of typing in one off commands and then to go back and execute the same command a few times for different files I have to edit the filename twice in each command. In my psuedo-code example I would only have to return to the previously entered command and edit only the filename string at the end.

I have tried,

```bash
touch "$(echo foo && chmod +x !$)"
```

but the filename is neither at the end of the string, and it doesn't seem to work because the last argument `!$` is the one passed to the command before `touch`.

Comment: please update the question to explain why a function is not an acceptable solution; based solely on what we've been provided so far ... you don't want to type a filename more than once ... you want to re-run a set of commands more than once (each time with a different filename); this is exactly what a function (in conjunction with the command line history) is good for and with detailed requirement it's likely you could define the function once (eg, add it to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`) and never have to edit it

Comment: @markp-fuso You make some good points. I think I let my mind wander and I was considering a general solution for use cases involving functions other than what my question stated. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ touch foo && chmod +x $_
```

Now:

```
$ ls -l foo
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me    0 mars  30 19:16 foo
```

Comment: The `echo` and expansion in your solution are unnecessary. You could merely use `touch foo && chmod +x $_`.

Comment: Post edited accordingly. Brainstorming in action ^^

Answer (score 5):

If all you ever do is issue the `touch / chmod` pair, a simple function should suffice:

```
touchx() { touch "$1"; chmod +x "$1"; }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ touchx myscript.sh
$ ls -l myscript.sh
-rwxrwx--x+ 1 username None 0 Mar 29 14:37 myscript.sh
```

On the other hand if the objective is to support a series of unknown-beforehand set of commands, another function may come in handy:

```
multicmd() {
    fname="$1"
    shift
    for cmd in "$@"
    do
        echo "##### $cmd $fname"
        $cmd "$fname"
    done
}

# or as a one-liner:

multicmd() { fname="$1"; shift; for cmd in "$@"; do echo "##### $cmd $fname"; $cmd "$fname"; done; }
```

Taking for a test drive

```
$ multicmd myscript.sh rm touch 'chmod +x' 'file' 'ls -l'
##### rm myscript.sh
##### touch myscript.sh
##### chmod +x myscript.sh
##### file myscript.sh
myscript.sh: empty
##### ls -l myscript.sh
-rwxrwx--x+ 1 username None 0 Mar 29 14:54 myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The `install` command is especially designed for this kind of purposes and can do much more:

```bash
$ install -T -m755 /dev/null foo
$ ls -l foo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 léa léa 0 mars  30 19:35 foo
```

Comment: can you add an example to your answer?

Comment: @qq4 **it's an example**, test it in a _terminal emulator_

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, `umask` may be a simple solution. `umask +x` will cause any file you create using the current shell to have execution privileges by default for example. If you're going to make a lot of files during a session and don't want to individually `chmod` them or write custom functions this would be a viable alternative.

The downside is that if you `touch` an existing file, this won't change its permissions. If that's what you want then use one of the other solutions instead.